# Django dropdown select get data from database

Tags: django

I have a table :

Cars with field carID,CarName

PaymentType field paymentTypeID, PaymentTypeName

Carprice field priceID,CarID,paymentTypeID, amountPrice

I already show Cars and paymentType to dropdown select.

how i can show Carprice after user selectCar and selectPayment?

best regards,
Capah Maga

Comment: make an api call using js, to get list of carprices, and fill them in the dropdown. If you want to do this using just django and no javascript, you will need to add a submit button after user select first two fields, process that data in view, then render the template again with the third dropdown

Comment: i don't want using API. how i can get list of carprices from javascript?

Comment: User submits form with first two fields selected, in your view function you query list of carprices according to that, and render the form again with the list of carprices in template context, so that you can show them in dropdown.